# Faster way to run command over remote server via ssh in bash

Tags: bash, ssh

Currently I am working with a local machine that does not have finger command built in and we do not have permission to install it either. However, there is a remote server that has it installed and can be used that way. I am using finger command to get First and Last name of the users. Here is the code below in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NAMES=("ssmith" "jnicol" "ahumph" "nkidma" "bbanne")
for name in ${NAMES[@]}; do
    theName=`ssh -qX 123.45.67.89 finger $name | awk 'NR==1{if($7!="???") print $7, $8}'`
    arr+=("$theName") #Appending name returned from command to global array
done
```

The above code works but it is super **slow**. Is there any **simpler** way to ssh over to remote server to run command and get list of all user(s) first and last name in single attempt, and then append all of those into an array like shown above? There are 100s of users in the system and doing ssh over to remote server for every single one of them is not going to be optimal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pay attention to the three points: `finger [-lmsp] [user ...] [user@host ...]`

Comment: `finger "${NAMES[@]}"`

Comment: Read up on using the `ControlMaster` option, which lets you share a single authenticated connection between multiple `ssh` clients.

Comment: You don't need `finger` on your machine. First and last name are information `finger` fetches from the password database. Why don't you use the password DB instead of ssh-ing to a machine that runs the finger daemon (which will probably soon be removed)?

Answer (score 0):

All, found the answer to this. I could do the following in my Local machine and still get user's first and last name.

```
FULLNAME=$(getent passwd $USER | cut -d : -f 5)
```

Thanks all.